# query cakephp2 with date dynamic

Tags: cakephp

how to do query in cakephp2, with a dynamic date from the form

```
SELECT centro_id, (sum(timestampdiff(minute, hora_inicio, hora_fin)))/(720*(SELECT datediff(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d'), '2013-07-01')))*100 FROM `sesions` where fecha BETWEEN '2013-07-01' and date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Please start formatting your code properly, people have done that many many times for you now. Also please be more specific with your questions / problem descriptions (what have you tried, what exactly is the problem, what exactly happens, etc...), StackOverflow is not a coding service, other people should be able to benefit from questions and answers too - thanks!

Comment: I hope that now this is ok